# How can I see changes with more than one insertion/deletion in git?

Tags: git

I'm using YUI Compressor in my project, so it automatically minify js and css. When I try to show diff in the files before commit to repo, there are many .min.* files with 2 changes (+-). Is there any easy way to display only files with more than 2 changes in git?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to see the diff of only a few select files, one thing you could do is call git diff only on individual files:

```
git diff <file1> <file2>
```

Comment: Is there way to call git diff with all files, except with some expression? Maybe it will be regex or something.